# maven dependency for cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws breaking the existing soap client

Tags: java, web-services, maven, soap

My spring mvc is giving call to one soap client. I have to integrate another soap client call in my application.
I have to add the new maven dependency for cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws. The version of previous cxf dependencies are 3.1.5 but when I am adding cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws with this version, I am getting bean creation exception in one of the old soap classes "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: QUALIFIED".
My previous soap client integration was through annotation but the new soap client has its mapping in xml. So, I need this cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws in my maven. I don't know what to do. Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run mvn dependency:tree and check for XmlSchema dependency. You must exclude old versions of it and use the one provided by CXF.